# Clipboard.setData times out in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this code present inside the onPressed of an IconButton, to copy some text to the clipboard, but it always times out.

```
await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "text to be copied"))
.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),
         onTimeout: () async {
                      Toast.show("inside timeout", context);
                    });
```